# If Else Error Requesting Bracket - Don't See The Error

Tags: java

Else If error - Java '(' Expected - Taking an on-line course.  Wrote some code for an on-line quiz and it was accepted by system.  Second quiz question was quite similar.  Code will not run and am not sure what is wrong.  Syntax structure seems similar to my first question's answer that worked.  What am I missing?  Java hobbyist newbie...

```
package com.JonEKreski;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        shouldWakeUp(false, -1);
        System.out.println("Dog is barking = " + barking);
    }
    public static boolean shouldWakeUp(boolean barking, int hourOfDay) {
        if ((hourOfDay < 0) || (hourOfDay > 23)) {
            barking = false;
        } else if {
            ((hourOfDay < 8) || (hourOfDay > 22));
            barking = true;
        } else {
            barking = false;
        }
        return barking;
    }
}
```

Comment: check your else if syntax.

Comment: [Java tutorial on if-else statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html).

Comment: You have a stray semi-colon on your else-if

Answer (score 0):

correct else if should be

```
else if ((hourOfDay < 8) || (hourOfDay > 22)){
    barking = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this:

```
} else if {
    ((hourOfDay < 8) || (hourOfDay > 22));
    barking = true;
} else {
 ...
```

with this:

```
} else if ((hourOfDay < 8) || (hourOfDay > 22)) {
    barking = true;
} else {
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was on line 9. Correct code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        shouldWakeUp(false, -1);
        System.out.println("Dog is barking = " + barking);
    }

    public static boolean shouldWakeUp(boolean barking, int hourOfDay) {
        if ((hourOfDay < 0) || (hourOfDay > 23)) {
            barking = false;
        } else if ((hourOfDay < 8) || (hourOfDay > 22)) {
            barking = true;
        } else {
            barking = false;
        }
        return barking;
    }
```